customize color of column chart in ant-design-charts v2.2.1
I want to change the color of the columns in the chart but I still haven't found a way with the new document

  const config = {
    xField: "title",
    yField: "value",
    label: {
      text: (d: any) => {
        console.debug("d", d);
        return `${(d.value * 100).toFixed(1)}%`;
      },
      textBaseline: "bottom",
    },
    style: {
        radiusTopLeft: 6,
        radiusTopRight: 6,
      },
    legend: false,
    colorField: "group",
    group: true,
  };

Change the color of columns in the chart

Try this:
Define your color palette array:
const COLOR_PALETTE = [
    "#ff87cd",
    "#2f97b7",
  ]

Then you can update your config file like this:
scale: {
    color: { range: COLOR_PALETTE },
  },

